# Order referencing by appearance AND number (natbib)

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing, natbib

I am currently trying to get the references to be listed **in order of appearance in my document**, rather than order in bibliography.

Some info:

I am using natbib:

```
    \usepackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}
    \citep{}
```

(as I want to be able to have references like: [2-5], and I want the numerical representation of the bibitem).

I have tried:\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}.

This works, but not when I have the **numbers** enabled for the natbib package; that is, the ordering I want works for non-numbered referencing, but **NOT** for numbered referencing.

Been look everywhere, can't find the answer!

Been through and removed .aux files a few times already.

Example of what I have:

```
    Piezoelectric technology [3][2].
```

Where as I want is:

```
    Piezoelectric technology [2][3].
```

without having to change the bib file.

I have no problem with using another type of bibliography package as long as I can order as I wish **and** concatenation of references, i.e: [3-5].

```
\documentclass[11pt , a4paper , twoside , openright ]{report} 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 
\begin{document} 
Hello, I want to cite this document with two citations, one which precedes the 
other in .bib, but in order here \cite{katz}\cite{mcgahey}.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{bibl} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Instead of providing two separate `\cite` commands, have you tried a single `\cite` command with two arguments, i.e., `\cite{katz,mcgahey}`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Try with `sort&compress` instead of `compress`, but you should use `\cite{katz,mcgahey}`

Comment: Seemed to solve it. I used `\cite{katz,mcgahey}` along with fixing a style sheet which my university requires I use. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments